# HTML picture tag with media queries and multiple file formats

Tags: html, image, media-queries

I am planning to start using HTML picture tags on my website. I know that with picture tags, it is possible to use media queries and serve differently-sized images and different file formats. But are the following things possible?

- To have 6 different image sizes both as jpeg and webp. The browser should prefer webp and jpeg versions to be served only as secondary options.
- As I understand, media queries are against the viewport width. Would there be any easy way to have a query against the current container width? For example, the viewport can be 1200px but the image's container only be 600px. In that case, serving 1200px wide image would be a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: Regarding your first question: Please read [MDN's `<picture>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) and [`<source>` documentations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source). In short, the first matching and supported `<source>` will be used.

Comment: @OskarGrosser, thank you. That is what I was guessing but got a confirmation now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`<picture>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) can be used to provide alternative sources for an image. It must have a default `<img>` element.

From top to bottom, the first matching and supported [`<source>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source)'s source will be used instead of the fallback image's. If you want to prefer WebP over JPEG, simply list the WebP `<source>`s first:

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="alternative.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="alternative.jpeg" type="image/jpeg">
  <img src="default.png">
</picture>
```

---

As for querying against the container: I believe this is currently not possible.

Ideally, the page is designed in a way where you (as the designer) know how the elements will be sized. If this is not the case, you can still estimate what sources to serve for certain sizes.

I highly recommend to read [MDN's *Responsive images* article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images). In short, you should use the following:

- Attribute `srcset`: A list of all alternative sources along with either their intrinsic widths or pixel density descriptors only.
- Attribute `sizes`: A list of media queries and the resulting slot sizes.

**Note**: The `px` unit in the `sizes` attribute refers to "CSS pixels". These CSS pixel don't refer to actual device pixel; they refer to virtual pixels that are scaled to be reasonably sized for the device. (Related: The [Viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag).)

The browser will calculate which source to use based on the source's and the slot's size, while considering the scale between device and CSS pixels.

Or in other words: With the information given via the attributes, the browser will choose the highest-quality image for your media (i.e. screen).

---

At a glance, I also found the blog [*Responsive images* by KeyCDN](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/responsive-images) informative.

Comment: Thank you for the whole answer. I have estimates about the element sizes. I also found a Javascript snippet that would dynamically generate srcset attribute based on the container size but perhaps, that solution would be unnecessarily complicated.